# Creating a header for a doubly linked list

Tags: c, gcc, header, doubly-linked-list

So I'm taking a course on Operating systems, and we've started the semester with a crash course in C programming. Our first 2 assignments were easy but I just can't for the life of me figure this one out.

So our professor had his TA create the following .c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "dll.h"

void init(Dll *dll, int n){
Node *prev = &(dll->head);
prev->prev = NULL;
Node *node;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    node = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    node->value = rand();
    node->prev = prev;
    node->next = NULL;
    prev->next = node;
    prev = node;
    printf("%d. ", i+1);
    printf("%d\n", node->value);
}
}
void print(Dll *dll){
Node *current;
current = dll->head.next;
while(current->next != NULL){
    printf("%d\n", current->value);
    current = current->next;
}
printf("%d\n", current->value);
}
void sort(Dll *dll){
int changed = 1;
while(changed==1){
    Node *current;
    current = dll->head.next;
    changed = 0;
    while(current->next != NULL){
        if(current->value > current->next->value){
            int value;
            value = current->value;
            current->value = current->next->value;
            current->next->value = value;
            changed = 1;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
}

}

int main(){
Dll dll;
init(&dll, 10);
print(&dll);
sort(&dll);
printf("\nSorted:\n");
print(&dll);
return 0;
}
```

And our assignment is to create the header file that we should implement to run the .c file. I've spent all day working on it and the best I can come up with is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Dll {
Dll *prev;
Dll *next;
int value;
} dll;


void *init(Dll *dll, int n);
void sort(Dll *dll);
void print(Dll *dll);
```

Whenever I run it with my .h I get the following errors in the command line (we're using gcc on linux):

```
In file included from dll.c:5:0:
dll.h:5:5: error: unknown type name ‘Dll’
dll.h:6:5: error: unknown type name ‘Dll’
dll.h:10:1: error: unknown type name ‘Dll’
dll.h:12:12: error: unknown type name ‘Dll’
dll.h:13:11: error: unknown type name ‘Dll’
dll.h:14:12: error: unknown type name ‘Dll’
dll.c:7:11: error: unknown type name ‘Dll’
dll.c:22:12: error: unknown type name ‘Dll’
dll.c:31:11: error: unknown type name ‘Dll’
dll.c: In function ‘main’:
dll.c:51:2: error: unknown type name ‘Dll’
```

I used other examples of these types of header files to make mine, but for some reason I just cannot figure this out. I would really appreciate any help you guys can give me.

**EDIT: ** When I change the name of to "Dll" it gives me:

```
In file included from dll.c:5:0:
dll.h:5:5: error: unknown type name ‘Dll’
dll.h:6:5: error: unknown type name ‘Dll’
dll.h:10:1: error: unknown type name ‘Type’
dll.h:12:5: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
dll.c:7:6: error: conflicting types for ‘init’
dll.h:14:7: note: previous declaration of ‘init’ was here
dll.c: In function ‘init’:
dll.c:8:2: error: unknown type name ‘Node’
dll.c:8:20: error: ‘Dll’ has no member named ‘head’
dll.c:9:6: error: request for member ‘prev’ in something not a structure or union
dll.c:10:2: error: unknown type name ‘Node’
dll.c:11:2: error: ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode
dll.c:11:2: note: use option -std=c99 or -std=gnu99 to compile your code
dll.c:12:11: error: ‘Node’ undeclared (first use in this function)
dll.c:12:11: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it         appears in
dll.c:12:17: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
dll.c:13:7: error: request for member ‘value’ in something not a structure or union
dll.c:14:7: error: request for member ‘prev’ in something not a structure or union
dll.c:15:7: error: request for member ‘next’ in something not a structure or union
dll.c:16:7: error: request for member ‘next’ in something not a structure or union
dll.c:19:22: error: request for member ‘value’ in something not a structure or union
dll.c: In function ‘print’:
dll.c:23:2: error: unknown type name ‘Node’
dll.c:24:15: error: ‘Dll’ has no member named ‘head’
dll.c:25:15: error: request for member ‘next’ in something not a structure or union
dll.c:26:25: error: request for member ‘value’ in something not a structure or union
dll.c:27:20: error: request for member ‘next’ in something not a structure or union
dll.c:29:24: error: request for member ‘value’ in something not a structure or union
dll.c: In function ‘sort’:
dll.c:34:3: error: unknown type name ‘Node’
dll.c:35:16: error: ‘Dll’ has no member named ‘head’
dll.c:37:16: error: request for member ‘next’ in something not a structure or union
dll.c:38:14: error: request for member ‘value’ in something not a structure or union
dll.c:38:31: error: request for member ‘next’ in something not a structure or union
dll.c:40:20: error: request for member ‘value’ in something not a structure or union
dll.c:41:12: error: request for member ‘value’ in something not a structure or union
dll.c:41:29: error: request for member ‘next’ in something not a structure or union
dll.c:42:12: error: request for member ‘next’ in something not a structure or union
dll.c:45:21: error: request for member ‘next’ in something not a structure or union
```

Comment: You will get some warnings with your code as well, as you declare `init` to return a `void*` but don't actually return anything.

Comment: You also access fields in the structure that doesn't exist, for example what is `dll->head`?

Comment: I'm not sure what `dll->head` is. I assume it's the beginning of the doubly linked list, but I'm not sure. The .c file isn't my code

Answer (score 1):

That should be:

```
typedef struct _Node{
   struct _Node *next;
   struct _Node *prev;
   int value;
}Node;
typedef struct _Dll{
   Node head;
};
```

Typo in your `typedef`.. `dll` is not the same as `Dll`

Also note, there is no `head` in your `struct _Dll`

Also, please let me know what `Node` is.

Comment: I had tried that before, but based on example I saw it looked like it didn't matter, and the lower case `dll` gave me far less errors. I added the output I'm getting now

Comment: it doesn't matter if it is lower case or upper case. What matters is that it should first compile.

Comment: I'm not sure, I don't quite know how to address that. I'm not sure if I need to make a `typedef struct` for it or not.

Comment: @Jon there is an undefined type in your program called `Node` - have you copy-pasted the program from elsewhere?

Comment: Yes, my assignment is to create the .h file that should go with the .c file provided.

Comment: @Jon from the code you've posted, the best I can understand from is this should be the structure in your header file

Answer (score 0):

In the question code, you have two type names:

```
struct Dll
```

And then typedef for it

```
dll
```

The keyword struct there is important, in C you must use it, unlike C++. Then in your code you use just Dll, which is not a known symbol for *C* compiler.

It's also fine to do this, no need to use different names:

```
typedef struct my_struct { ... } my_struct;
```

Another problem in queation code is, you have parameter name dll, as well as the typedef name dll.